# Python refactoring fails in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, automated-refactoring

I switched to Visual Studio Code for Python programming recently. Below is my Python configuration in Visual Studio Code settings:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/hzhang/.virtualenvs/env-2.7/bin/python",
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/Users/hzhang/Work/xxx/shared_modules"
],
```

Basically, I just configure the Python interpreter and add one extra shared module path.

When I try to refactor a variable name, it throws this *error* which says `rope` is not installed, and it doesn't work even I install it. Based on my understanding, refactor variables is a feature of Visual Studio Code, and it shouldn't rely on any specific language.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Once I installed `rope`, refactor was still not working. It popups this error:

[image]

```
I am on Python 2.7
Visual Studio Code: Version 1.19.3 (1.19.3)
Rope version: 0.10.7
```

Comment: There is recently filed bug on this in the python for vscode extension: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/613.

Comment: @ElliottBeach Thanks for your comment, I would keep an eye on the open issue!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Renaming of variables is not a native Visual Studio Code feature for languages other than JavaScript and TypeScript.

It is specific to each language, and functionality is provided by separate extensions, specific to each language. The Python extension you have installed, uses the Rope library to perform refactoring/renaming of python variables and the like. So yes, you'll need to install it by closing in the `Install rope` button.

If you don't have the `Install rope` button, you can just go to cmd and type `pip install rope`. That should do the job as well.

If it doesn't work even after installing it, please could you file an issue on the Python extension GitHub repository.

Comment: Hey Don. Thanks for your reply. I have installed `rope` before asking the question and it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for updating the issue with further information. Please could you file an issue on github. We'll look into this from there. Looks like the rope library is falling over with some error.

Comment: pleasesee the comment under my question，the bug has been issued already

Answer (score 2):

Update from the filed bug: [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) users need to install the Anaconda package instead of the regular pip default install that Visual Studio Code provides.

This worked for me:

```sh
conda search rope # The latest right now is 0.11.0
conda install --name mypy27env rope
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, miniconda:
I had this issue using the "VSCode Python Plugin", when selecting "conda" install for rope.

I changed the active env with Terminal using "conda activate env". Then with "conda list", I saw Build Row was at value py_0 and at version 0.16.
I've chosen conda remove rope
Then, installing with pip (rope version 0.17.0):  pip install rope
"conda list" gave me now pypi_0 as value in Build row
Restart VSCode

Summarize, one of this helped:
 - Reinstalling rope with pip in the active conda environment
 - Restarting VSCode